# How to monitor if my App switches from running in foreground to running in background and vice versa?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get informed I my app switches between running in foreground and running in background and vice versa.

[Here](http://tips.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-how-to-check-if-the-app-is-in-background-or-foreground/) I got the following code to detect if my app runs in background:

```
  private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
      List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
      for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
        if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
          for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
            if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
              isInBackground = false;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
      ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
      if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
        isInBackground = false;
      }
    }

    return isInBackground;
  }
```

This might work but I need something which calls the function when the state changes. I might can do something like this:

```
BroadcastReceiver appStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("TEST", "appStateReceiver: "+isAppIsInBackground(context));
  }
```

};

Now I need to register the above Broadcast receiver somehow:

```
IntentFilter appStateFfilter = // ???? this is the part I do not know about
context.registerReceiver(appStateReceiver, appStateFfilter);
```

I will not use `onPause()` and `onResume()` because I should do this on every activity.

**How do I register a `BroadcastReceiver` to monitor if the app switches states (i.e., running in foreground, running in background)? Are there any other solutions than my approach which notify you when the app state has changed?**

Comment: What about using `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods of your activities?

Comment: I will not use ``onPause()`` and ``onResume()`` because I should do this on every activity.

Comment: Create a base activity then, and make all your activities extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `Service` class which monitors whether your app is running in foreground or background and can register your `BroadcastReciever` from there.

```
private boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                         Handler mmHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
                        mmHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //code
                                }
                            });
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
            Handler mmHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
                mmHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //code
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```

This method returns true if your app is running in background. Write this method inside your `Service` class and use the return value accordingly.

Do this for your BroadCastReceiver :

```
  Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(); 
                                        broadcastIntent.setAction(com.example.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED); 
                                        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 
                                        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: Could you please post some code for that claim. I have no idea how to do that monitoring.

Comment: How do I start the Service?

Comment: `startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Service.class)); ` Replace Service.class with your class name

Comment: Where do I put ``Intent broadcastIntent ... ``?